# List Comprehension "Translation"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Can someone translate this list comprehension into multiple lines, really having difficulties understanding it!

```
friends = [i for x, i in enumerate(friends) if (x+1) % action]
```

Comment: Note that this is *extremely* misleading. `i` is typically used for anonymous indices, `x` for anonymous values. But `enumerate` produces them as `(index, value)` pairs, so `x` is actually the index here, and `i` the value. It's like someone's being intentionally confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It should be this if expanded. I created a list called `temp_list` and I added the `print` for clarity.

```
temp_list = []
for x, i in enumerate(friends):
    if (x+1) % action:
        temp_list.append(i)

friends = temp_list
print(friends)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating over `friends` using enumerate, we can assume `friends` already has some values in it.

The list comprehension is replacing the original value of `friends` list with another list that we get as output of comprehension logic. Note all this is done in 1 line.

If we break the comprehension to expanded form, we cannot iterate over the list and change the list at the same time (we can do that but its not recommended and we may get wrong values).

So expanded form of above list comprehension would look like :

```
temp = []
for x, i in enumerate(friends):
    if (x+1) % action:
        temp.append(i)

friends = temp
```

Answer (score -2):

It look like this when expanded:

```
friends = [] # Intialize the friends list

# For loop with enumerate function where x is the index and i the value
for x, i in enumerate(friends): 
    if (x+1) % action:
        friends.append(i)
```

Comment: This is wrong; since it doesn't use a temporary `list`, this drops the prior reference to `friends` they're iterating over before it begins looping, so it always ends up with an empty `list`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yeah you are right. Thanks for correcting this. :)